# find most recent file in directory

Tags: vb.net, getfiles

I'm trying to load the most recent file from a directory, but my following code doesn't work. Am i getting something obvious terribly wrong?!

```
Dim myFile = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\XML Logs").OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First()
```

I get two error messages:

> Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method '`Public Function OrderByDescending(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of String, TKey)) As System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of String)`' defined in '`System.Linq.Enumerable`' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

And:

> '`LastWriteTime`' is not a member of '`String`'.

Answer (score 8):

You could make the Linq function use FileInfo objects instead of strings.

```
Dim myFile = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\XMLLogs").OrderByDescending(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime).First()
```

Comment: -1: the OP could do that, or he could simply use the method he intended to use, which is `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, as @GSerg says below.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was just providing another possible answer. He doesn't specify whether he wants a string as an answer or not.

Answer (score 6):

[`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) returns `String()`.

Apparently you meant [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) which returns `FileInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the file's info so I wrote mine up a little differently.

```
Dim myFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\XML Logs").OrderBy(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime).Max())
```